# Is the adiabatic theorem in Quantum mechanics valid in general for Non-Hermitian Hamiltonians?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, research-level, hamiltonian, approximations, adiabatic

Is the [adiabatic theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adiabatic_theorem) in Quantum mechanics valid in general for Non-Hermitian Hamiltonians? The proofs I have come across for adiabatic theorem all assume at some point in the proof that the Hamiltonian is Hermitian. Is there a more general proof? Is it valid to any extent at all for non-Hermitian Hamiltonians?

Note:I have used the term non-hermitian but the more general case of non-self adjoint is what i am interested in .

Comment: Comment to the post (v2): So you're willing to give up [conservation of probability](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unitarity_%28physics%29)?

Comment: I am interested in  both the cases,including that of dissipative systems with no conservation of probability and PT symmetric Hamiltonians as well.

Comment: Tip: [Let's not have posts look like revision histories](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/q/5886/2451).

Comment: I didn't want to change non-hermitian to non-self adjoint at every point and i figured a lot more people might take a shot at the question if it stayed non-Hermitian. Anyway, the popular proofs don't seem to make any assumptions about if it is  finite or an infinite dimensional Hilbert space.

Comment: I recommend to write non-selfadjoint rather than non-Hermitian everywhere. It makes sense at any reader-level.

Comment: PT symmetric quantum theory in the end is equivalent to usual hermitian one (at least when PT symmetry is unbroken) so I think all theorems will hold for them as usual.